# WFP driver test always failed due to machine state for Win11 on cloud azure

Tags: azure, wfp, driver-signing

I built up an automation for run the HLK driver test and sign flow for NDIS driver.

This time I want to use it to test the WFP driver, however, when running HLK driver test on Win 11 platform, no matter 22H or 23H, the WFP-related test cases were all failed. The reason of failed is "Machine state not meet the requirement", Hibernation: False, Suspension: False.

I checked the MSDN documents, the hardware requirement of WindowsFilterPlatform_test is to support S1-3 and S4 state, hibernation and suspension.

I tried to subscribe preview version of azure to enable "hibernation" of vm, but it still not work.

Does anyone have the experience to run the WFP driver test for win11 on the cloud azure?

How could I bypass this error, or I only could do it on the real machine that built-with hibernation and suspension?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It used to be that the tests had to be run on real hardware and not virtual machines. Not sure if that's changed but I doubt it.

Comment: Yes, I also heard that too. However, when the HLK test combinations are become more and more, using cloud Azure would be more effectively I think. For NDIS driver, it works, but for WFP driver, it fails. Just wondering if there has any tips could make it works on cloud. I also tried to contact the MS support. Will update if I got some useful information from MS.